# Spring Cloud APIGW, Spring Boot and OpenAPI issue - CORS issue

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using Spring Boot and Microservices stack using Spring Cloud APIGW. I am using the same code mentioned here: https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/

When I hit any endpoint, I don't see response is coming and getting below error.

> Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.0.2:49382/' from origin 'http://localhost:8060' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Source code: https://github.com/piomin/sample-spring-microservices-new

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by myself looking at suggestion here: [Spring Cloud Gateway and Springdoc OpenAPi integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953605/spring-cloud-gateway-and-springdoc-openapi-integration) and https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1144

I had to add below in apigw-service in `application.properties` file

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

Also, in each microservice, you need to add below bean

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I followed all the steps that you mentioned and I am still getting this error. Weird.

Comment: server.forward-headers-strategy=framework

The above property will go inside all the microservice which are running behind api-gateway and then it works. :) 

Thanks a lot buddy @PAA

Comment: The Java code is not required. application.properties is sufficient to fix this issue.

Comment: @an0nh4x0r was correct, this fixed it for me, though just the property was needed and the bean wasn't required.

Answer (score 1):

You should add swagger configuration

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {
    @Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")
})
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("springdoc-openapi-ui") String serviceTitle, @Value("1.6.12") String serviceVersion) {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    return new OpenAPI()
            .components(
                    new Components().addSecuritySchemes(
                            securitySchemeName,
                            new SecurityScheme()
                                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                    .scheme("bearer")
                                    .bearerFormat("JWT")
                    )
            )
            .security(List.of(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName)))
            .info(new Info().title(serviceTitle).version(serviceVersion));
}
}
```